# .Net Chart Legend Line height

Tags: c#, .net, charts

I am using the .Net Chart with a legend.
The legend style is set to Table.

When rendered the legend bar thickness is not as desired (It is too skinny).  I would like to increase the height of the legend bars. See image below.

[image: Snipped of chart image with skinny Legend bars]

Comment: After searching around I'm afraid this isn't possible. The legend is supposed to look like the series is drawn but even after changing the series line width (by the unlikely `Series.BorderWidth` property, the legend doesn't change. Looks like the best option is to draw a thicker line in the `PostPaint` event..

Comment: Thanks for your effort - Could you give me a pointer on how to do this in PostPaint?